# Как определить сказуемое в предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, синтаксический-разбор

Помогите определить сказуемое: «Так оно и было на самом деле».

Comment: Только после того как дадите свой вариант. Совет: не мудрствуйте, здесь всё просто. ))

Answer (score 3):

Мне этот вариант не кажется простым.

Вот пример из учебника: "Теперь всё **будет по-новому**". Это **составное именное сказуемое**, именная часть выражена наречием.

Приведенный пример имеет  примерно такую же структуру:**Так оно и было** на самом деле". Тогда местоименное наречие "так" тоже является именной частью сказуемого.

Ведь речь идет не о существовании предмета, а об его признаке.

Comment: А вы различаете "по-новому" и "на самом деле"? Последнее, как говорят лингвисты, в исходной фразе лексически опустошено. То есть, по-простому, ничего не значит.

Comment: Я думаю, что "на самом деле" к основе предложения не относится, его можно опустить  (так оно всё и было).

Comment: Я бы сказал, что основа здесь: "оно было". Зачем мудрить?!

Comment: Не хочется мудрить, но сказуемое, по определению,  состоит из двух частей: грамматическая часть выражает время, наклонение, а семантическая часть выражает признак. В простом глагольном сказуемом эти части совмещены, а в составном - разделены. Сравним два примера: (1) Всё это БЫЛО в их совместной статье. (2)  Всё это БЫЛО для меня НОВО. Думаю, что сказуемые здесь разного вида (простое и составное именное). В простом сказуемом признаком является само существование предмета.

Comment: @Sibylla, что такое "часть сказумого"? Я бы еще понял, скажи вы о "двух сущностях" или чего-то подобного...

Comment: *Я бы сказал, что основа здесь: "оно было".* - да вы-то сказать-то можете что угодно. А что вы хотите сказать - это уже странно...

Comment: Цитата из  книги Кустова Г.И.  "Синтаксис современного русского языка" (2023). " Сказуемое имеет два аспекта, грамматический и семантический, и выражает два вида значений: грамматическое и вещественное. В грамматическом аспекте сказуемое выражает предикативность (время и наклонение).

Comment: В семантическом аспекте сказуемое выражает конкретный признак (процессуальный и непроцессуальный), приписываемый подлежащему. Если оба значения - грамматическое и вещественное - выражаются в одном слове, то сказуемое является простым. Если вещественное значение выражается словом, не имеющим грамматических показателей времени и модальности, то сказуемое получает вспомогательный компонент и является составным".

Comment: "Так оно и было на самом деле". Предложение двусоставное, вид сказуемого зависит от того, что считать признаком: само существование (оно было) или местоименное наречие "так" (оно было так/таким). Можно сравнить с предложением: Таким он и был на самом деле.

Answer (score 1):

> Помогите определить сказуемое: «Так оно и было на самом деле».

.

Я бы, ориентируясь на мнение Бабайцевой, в качестве сказуемого в этом предложении выделил  бы слово ***было.***

.

Бабайцева в книге *"Система односоставных предложений в современном русском языке" (2004)* предложения типа ***Так было, Так есть, Так будет*** рассматривает как односоставные со сказуемыми ***было, есть, будет.*** Местоимение-наречие ***так*** в этих предложениях Бабайцева считает обстоятельством:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И далее:

> Позиция подлежащего в предложениях с ***так*** может быть замещена
>   словами ***это, всё, оно.***

Comment: Сомнительно. Без "так" предложение семантически неполноценно, если "так" не в начале предложения, а если в начале, то это скорее всего и не обстоятельство, а частица.

Comment: "О, если б это было так! ― воскликнула она". Интересно, а это какое предложение?

Answer (score 0):

Я склоняюсь к мысли, что здесь недостаточно информации, чтобы однозначно вычленить структуру.
Если логическое ударение падает на "так" (а это наиболее вероятный вариант), то логично считать сказуемое составным именным - с местоименным наречием "так" в функции именной части.  В этом случае утверждается, что "оно" было так, а не как-то по-другому. Можно перенести "так" на другую позицию: *"Оно было так..."*

*Прим. Этот вариант семантической трактовки slava1949 рассматривает как единственно возможный, при этом "так" у него становится обстоятельством, с чем я решительно не согласен по причине семантической неполноценности "было" в данной конструкции. Т. е. на роль смыслового глагола при таком понимании семантики "было" не годится.*

Если же "так" - усилительная частица, а логическое ударение на "было", т. е. говорится  что "оно" существовало, происходило. В этом случае можно поменять глагол, но не место частицы: *"так оно и существовало самом деле!"*. В этом случае глагол "быть" становится смысловым и соответвенно выступает в голи простого глагольного сказуемого.

Наличие этих двух трактовок и показывает, что без контекста однозначного ответ на вопрос нет.